# jquery evalution not worked in less.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

i am using jquery function below

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()`
```

in my less file.

when i chrunch it to css 
 i am getting compiler error

i am using crunch software

```
Compiler Errors
You are using JavaScript, which has been disabled. (Line: 10)
Filename: cont.less
```

i want window or device height at less file only.

i have already try to include less.js but still it is not working.

plz help me.

Comment: Even if it compiles with Crunch this code do not make any sense since you're precompiling (`@winheight` will just contain some garbage) it, and there's *no* HTML page `window` (neither anything of JQuery at all) at that moment. This code would "work" *only* if it's compiled "client-side" (which is [not recommended](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/matthew-dean/Crunch/issues/119) Javascript is disabled in Crunch prior to version 2.0 (which is not yet released).

Comment: That explains why you are receiving the "You are using Javascript, which has been disabled" message: it is not a feature that you can use with Crunch 1.9.3.

Comment: thnks ,is there any other way or other software to do it bcoz i want window height value in css

Comment: @MinalTelgade There are ways to set an element to match the height of the window, yes. You can set `height: 100%;` if you also set `height: 100%` for all parents of that div (including `html` and `body`), for instance. Look around for ways to match window height and you'll find lots of helpful answers. :)